# Use USB Drive files in html using Apache2

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2, raspberry-pi3

So i have a Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest OS (10-04-2021) and i have apache2 running. I created a website which is in the directory /var/www/html/ with a few folders (e.g css, img, etc.) and i used the image tag with src="" to the usb drive path, but the video doesn´t load. I tried, if i made any mistakes while coding the website. So i also placed the website folder on the desktop with also the video path to my usb drive and i could play it on the website. I can´t place the .mp4 files in the /var/www/html/ path just because my SD card only has a few GB and my video folder is about 100 GB. How can i use my .mp4 files from my USB drive on the server/localhost?

What i tried and didn´t work was:

```
chmod -R a+r /media/pi/KINGSTON/*
```

I am just a beginner with raspberry pi and its OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a totally correct behavior. For security reasons Apache won't let you access files outside the document root, which in your case should be `/var/www/html/`. There are multiple approaches to do this, the first is to create symlinks in the document root and instruct apache2 to follow symlinks in the configuration file. Another approach is to use aliases. You can read [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside)